# How do I remove an item from recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I remove an item from the recycler view?

I have the following code

in

```
 class LibraryAdapter(val list: ArrayList<Book>): RecyclerView.Adapter<LibraryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

  holder.removeBtn.setOnClickListener {
        this.removeItem(position)
        MUser.removeFromLibrary(list[position].id)
    }
```

Then I have the function

```
fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: I want to remove an item from recycler view.

Comment: Until now what does your code do?

Comment: It removes the item below the item that the user tries to remove and then also crashes the app - out of index error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```